# How to change the state of a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]I am new to react and started working on to change the state of the component. May I ask please how to use the proper objects to manipulate the values?

**Header.js component**

```
//component with state and constructor

import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Header extends Component{
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {colors: this.props.color};
    }

    changeHeaderColor(){
        //console.log('Change_header_color_was_clicked');
        this.setState({
            colors: this.props.colors = 'yellow'});
    })
    
    render(){
        return(            
                <h1 style={{color:this.state.colors}}>This is the header Component  <button onClick={this.changeHeaderColor}>Change Header Color</button></h1>
        );
    }
}
```

**App componenet**

```
...

return (
      <div className="App">
          
          <Header color={'blue'}/> 
          <Header color={'red'}/>

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the function in constructor like:

```
this.changeHeaderColor = this.changeHeaderColor.bind(this);
```

or change this:

```
changeHeaderColor(){
    this.setState({colors: this.props.colors = 'yellow'});
})
```

to arrow function which do not have their own `this`:

```
changeHeaderColor = () => {  
    this.setState({colors: this.props.colors = 'yellow'});
})
```

[Passing Functions to Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just put `this.setState({colors: 'yellow'});`

Comment: thank you for your reply. But it gives me Type Error!

Comment: I attached the image.

Answer (score 0):

in the constructor you have to bind the `changeHeaderColor` method like this:

`this.changeHeaderColor = this.changeHeaderColor.bind(this)`